# Unable to call another API if one API running background after response send to client in ASP.net Core API. it causing error in same mobile APP

Tags: asp.net-core

I have two API's

1. Submitting data to database and process to outside services
2. getting data to Android APP

In the first API when we are saving data to database then we send respond to the mobile app. After that, we are processing to outside services.

When we get the response from the server to mobile app before processing to outside server unable to connect second API. Processing to outside servers running we get the error as 502 bad gateway. If processing to outside servers completed we didn't get any error

Below is the code. I have tried two ways.

1)

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateShipment([FromBody] UpdateShipmentCommand command)
{
    try
    {
        SavetoDatabase();

        return ok(result);
    }
    catch ()
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        Response.OnCompleted(async () =>
        {
            // code related to processing to out side servers
            //tried with synchronous and asynchronous

        }
   }
}
```

2. 

```
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateShipment([FromBody] UpdateShipmentCommand command)
{
    try
    {
        SavetoDatabase();

        _ = Task.Run(() =>
         // code related to processing to out side servers
         //tried with synchronous and asynchronous
        );
        return ok(result);
    }
    catch ()
    {
    }    
}
```

Comment: I really failed to understand your question. Could you pls explained it in another way?

Comment: Needs more info.